# Is it possible to specify which Google font to use per language on a web page?

Tags: css, unicode, google-fonts

I have a single page which needs one Google font for English characters and a different Google font for Thai characters.

It's possible to do use this using the `@font-face` syntax by defining which [unicode character range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@font-face/unicode-range) should use which font.

However Google fonts don't give you any option to use the `@font-face` syntax. Is there any way to specify unicode character range when importing fonts using Google's `@import` or `<link>` declarations?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to manually find this syntax by loading the URL provided by Google. For example, the `@import` rule for Noto Sans Thai is this:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+Thai:wght@200;400&display=swap');
```

Loading [that URL directly](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Sans+Thai:wght@200;400&display=swap) shows you the `@font-face` declarations.

Unfortunately, these are fixed in time and will eventually go stale, when the font is updated. This means future users will always need to download this specific version of the font even though they may have a more up-to-date version cached in their browser.